# Python UNO (libreoffice): How to enable auto filters for a sheet

Tags: python, libreoffice, openoffice.org, uno

I have a program, that creates a CSV file.

Now I'd like to use a Python UNO script, which shall do several things:

1.) open the csv file in a spread sheet

2.) enable auto filter for all columns

3.) create a macro and add it to the document

4.) save the file as ODS file

This question concerns only 2.)

1.) is working

for 3.)  I will probably create another question 
1.) Is working (with pyoo and with unotools)

My steps so far:

I start manually:

```
libreoffice --accept='socket,host=localhost,port=2202;urp;' --norestore --nologo --nodefault
```

My python script:

With pyoo

```
import pyoo
# Step 0) connect to UNO bridge
desktop = pyoo.Desktop('localhost', 2002)

# Step 1) open the doc and get the sheet
# This works only if the field separator is a comma.
# I don't know how for example to specify tab as separator instead
doc = desktop.open_spreadsheet('tst.csv')
# I see the spreadsheet opening
sheet = doc.sheets[0] # I get an object of type Sheet

# Step2) set autofilter for active sheet
# no idea how to do

# Step3) create a macro and add it to the document
# no idea how to do but will create another question as 
# soon as step2 is solved

# Step 4) save the sheet
doc.save("tst_pyoo.ods")
```

Or with unotools

```
import unotools
from unotools.component.calc import Calc
from unotools.unohelper import convert_path_to_url

# Step 0) connect to UNO bridge
context = unotools.connect(unotools.Socket('localhost', 2002))

# Step 1) open document
doc = Calc(ctx, convert_path_to_url('tst.csv')
# I see the spreadsheet opening
sheet = doc.get_sheet_by_index(0)
# I get an object of type unotools.component.calc.Spreadsheet

# Step2) set autofilter for active sheet
# no idea how to do

# Step3) create a macro and add it to the document
# no idea how to do but will create another question as 
# soon as step2 is solved

# Step 4)
doc.store_to_url(convert_path_to_url("tst_unotools.ods"))
```

Thanks in advance for any feedback

Comment: Thinking ahead  to your next question, will the macro in step 3 be written in Basic or Python?

Comment: either would be OK. Preference for python, but Basic is fine.
The macro would be some rather basic stuff.

Comment: Obe more comment.

If I could perform step 3 and then execute the macro, then the macro could perform setting the autofilter.
Not very elegant, but also a potential solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is code that uses straight PyUNO rather than a wrapper library.  It is adapted from http://www.imaccanici.org/en.libreofficeforum.org/node/5413.html.

```
import os
import uno

class UnoObjs:
    "Initializes and stores UNO objects to connect to a document."""
    def __init__(self, filepath=None):
        localContext = uno.getComponentContext()
        resolver = localContext.ServiceManager.createInstanceWithContext(
            "com.sun.star.bridge.UnoUrlResolver", localContext )
        self.ctx = resolver.resolve(
            "uno:socket,host=localhost,port=2002;urp;"
            "StarOffice.ComponentContext")
        self.smgr = self.ctx.ServiceManager
        desktop = self.smgr.createInstanceWithContext(
            "com.sun.star.frame.Desktop", self.ctx)
        if filepath:
            fileUrl = uno.systemPathToFileUrl(os.path.realpath(filepath))
            self.document = desktop.loadComponentFromURL(
                fileUrl, "_default", 0, ())
        else:
            self.document = desktop.getCurrentComponent()

def add_autofilter(unoObjs):
    """This adds an autofilter by selecting only the filled spreadsheet area. 
    NOTE: If any cell in the header row of the selection is empty this will
    trigger a popup for interactive user action (must click Yes for the
    Autofilter column header message box)
    """
    dispatcher = unoObjs.smgr.createInstanceWithContext(
        "com.sun.star.frame.DispatchHelper", unoObjs.ctx)
    controller = unoObjs.document.getCurrentController()
    sheet = unoObjs.document.getSheets().getByIndex(0)
    # select a sufficiently big "guess" area, hopefully
    guessRange = sheet.getCellRangeByPosition(0, 0, 150, 10000)
    # look up the actual used area within the guess area
    cursor = sheet.createCursorByRange(guessRange)
    cursor.gotoEndOfUsedArea(False)
    lastcol = cursor.RangeAddress.EndColumn
    lastrow = cursor.RangeAddress.EndRow
    # select the filled part of the spreadsheet
    actualRange = sheet.getCellRangeByPosition(0, 0, lastcol, lastrow)
    controller.select(actualRange)
    # add autofilter
    dispatcher.executeDispatch(
        unoObjs.document.getCurrentController(), ".uno:DataFilterAutoFilter",
        "", 0, ())

add_autofilter(UnoObjs("tst.csv"))
```

Dispatcher calls such as `.uno:DataFilterAutoFilter` are difficult to figure out the parameters.  In most cases it's better to use UNO API calls such as [XTextCursor](https://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/text/XTextCursor.html) instead.  However there are a few options to figure out dispatcher calls:

- Use the macro recorder.
- Look through a list like [this one](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Development/DispatchCommands).
- Find the calls in the LibreOffice source code.  This is the most reliable, but it can still sometimes be difficult to determine the arguments.

Regarding dispatcher calls, see https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=61127.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's working if I do a minor modification to your script:

It seems, that 
    `fileUrl = uno.systemPathToFileUrl(filepath)`
fails if it gets a relative path name passed.

If I add

   `import os`

at the beginning of the file and write

`fileUrl = uno.systemPathToFileUrl(os.path.realpath(filepath))`

your script works.

Is there any good way (documentation page) to see all actions, that one can perform with UNO?

Guessing the string ".uno:DataFilterAutoFilter" and guessing it's parameters is tricky and was my main problem finding the answer,

Comment: Well, I did have `os.path.realpath` in there originally but took it out to make the code shorter.  Apparently it was necessary after all.  I edited the answer to include the code and also explain dispatcher calls.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to modify the `content.xml` directly contained in the .ods file with python?

My aim is also to apply an autofilter in LibreOffice on Windows 10.
I can't find any documentation whatsoever.

But I found that if you unzip an .ods file, in the content.xml file there are the following lines of xml

```
<table:database-ranges>
                <table:database-range table:name="__Anonymous_Sheet_DB__0" table:target-range-address="Sheet1.A1:Sheet1.B3" table:display-filter-buttons="true"/>
</table:database-ranges>
```

Is there a way to read and modify the content.xml using the lxml module of python and in that way apply the autofilter in LibreOffice?